# html5 database passing variable in LIKE statement

Tags: database, html, variables

I want to pass variable in html5 database for search.
Bellow is the example of what I want:

```
var sear= "Hello World"   // for example 
var test = sear.split(" ");
var test3 = "\"%"+ test.join('%\", \"%')+"%\"";

var test4 = [];  

for (var i=2; i<=test.length; i++) {  
    test4[i] = " OR (D_Indications LIKE ?)";  
} 
var test5="SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE (D_Indications LIKE ?)"+ test4.join(" ");
```

now I want it to search the database by "Hello OR World" the code for it is.

```
tx.executeSql(test5, [test3],function (tx, results) {
    // display from database
});
```

but it is not searching when I pass variable into it rather it finds when I put `tx.executeSql(test5, ["%Hello%", "%World%"]`

Answer (score 0):

This page should help....
http://rickosborne.org/blog/2010/03/html5-in-browser-sql-database-storage/

Basically surround the search words variable with % then pass as argument to the SQL using LIKE and ? to reference the variable.

So something like this...

```
var searchWords = "%words%";

tx.executeSql("SELECT * from table WHERE (name LIKE ?);",[searchWords],renderFunction,errorFunction;
```